# Substitute to css outline-color: invert

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

Long time ago, with outdated browsers (chrome38) people could make boxes...

It was possible to use `outline-color: invert` to choose a color who was the exact opposite of the background.

Today, such a great feature does not exist anymore :( Do yo have an idea for me who just want to display boxes with borders of the opposite color of the background ?

(today chrome (39) compute `outline-color: invert` to `outline-color:transparent`.

before that `outline-color: invert` rendered to `outline-color: rgb(255,255,255)` on a black brackground.)

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Do you have JavaScript available?

Comment: Yes sure ;) But that was not the point.

Comment: I can’t think of a way to do this with pure CSS. A CSS pre-processor could do it; or JavaScript. In any case, it would be complicated.

Comment: Yeah, that is what i thought, but i would not be surprised if some css wizard found a way to do that with a tricky combination of shadows and blendings... :)

Comment: Important to bear in mind before using this for text, focus outlines, UI elements etc: this does not necessarily result in good enough colour contrast to meet [WCAG accessibility standards](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/) and be readable. Always check your contrast ratios. Not saying the original poster was going to do this but I think this could be useful info for people finding this post. See [codepen example](https://codepen.io/peterjcole/pen/gOBYYpB)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps this does the trick for you?

```css
.background {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.box {
  border: 3px solid white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 160px;
}
.invert {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="background" style="background: #ff0000">
  <div class="box invert"></div>
</div>

<div class="background" style="background: #000000">
  <div class="box invert"></div>
</div>

<div class="background" style="background: #ffffff">
  <div class="box invert"></div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/Frikki/pen/BNpKYb

Comment: I'm quite impressed by that ([extended demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lzru6mgt/)); I hadn't come across `mix-blend-mode` before.

Comment: Same as davidThomas, pretty impressed by the trick and never seen before. Thanks @FrederikKrautwald for this nice trick ;)